# NetBeans missing project categories

Tags: java, netbeans

After installing Netbeans few months ago (never used it) all categories were present but NB was missing Java application in file types, so I decided to reinstall NB and Java JDK. I downloaded JDK 8 with NetBeans pack, and now I have only XML and Other category. After searching web, and trying all solutions (deleting .superId file and userdata NB folder, reinstall...) problem remains. [image]

P.S. I also tried installing Java plugins, but nothing changed. NetBeans is 8.2 vers.

These are installed plugins under Java name.
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked the Plugins dialog under Tools? Inevitably that's where all that stuff comes from, but surprising you don't have just the basics.

Comment: Yes I have, but I didn't know what to install (never used Java or NB), so I installed few things and as I said before, nothing changed. Beside that NB should have more categories by default, then just those two.

Comment: I've edited original post to include screen for all installed Java plugins, since I'll be using it just for desktop apps, only thing I need in projects is Java Desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to create a "New File" rather than a "New Project".
If you click "New File" you will only have the categories included in your first screenshot, if you click "New Project" you will then see the Java category:
[New Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT1qg.png)